# CF : ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused

Tags: cloud-foundry

So, I have recently started using CF and am using the same to publish a nodejs app to my cf space.

> As suggested in the CF wiki, I have used the **nodejs_buildpack** to
>   build my app so that can be run via CF PaaS.
>
> Although I don't need this if I push my own cached
>   node_modules dependency folder in the **CF Space** , please correct me if I am wrong ?

Following screenshots represent the output of cf push ,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Output of : **CF logs STARS --recent**

[image]

manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: STARS
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
  memory: 256m
  disk_quota: 512MB
  instances: 1
  command: npm run build
```

I don't understand why 8080 fails as this works like charm on my machine. i.e. **localhost:8080**

I do set the express in the following way though,

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

// set up listening
app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    opn('http://localhost:' + app.get('port'))
  }
})
```

**--Update--**

As suggested by @K.AJ in the answer below I have tried to increase the memory limit in my manifest from 256 to 512 and you know what it started working. :)

But its a little strange that the allocation 179.4M in memory and 206.1M on disk is present. Looks like the addition of these two is considered in the deployment process.

My updated configuration is ,

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);`

In the above statement, the port is 8080, only when running locally.

On cloud platforms like PCF, you have no control on which port an app will be running.

If you look closely to the error message, your app is crashing due to out of memory error. The 256MB memory is not enough for it. Try setting it to 1GB first, get it working and then optimize it.

Assuming, you have successfully deployed your app, run `cf apps`. It should list you the deployed apps along with the route.

Copy the route url for your app and run it in browser. You should be able to see your app, provided your app instance is healthy and in running state.

Please go through documentation on PCF

- https://docs.pivotal.io
- https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-3/devguide/index.html
- https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-3/devguide/index.html#deploy

Comment: I see that the app is not deployed due to out of memory but the size of the app with the dependencies downloaded on my machine is 135 Mb only. I am working in a corporate environment where the space in CF was allocated to me by someone else. I will check with the operations guy and try with the increased memory too in the manifest and update here.

Comment: Thanks, after updating memory to 1G it started working. its memory issue